# libsodium crypto_sign_open returns unsigned message adding some characters

Tags: c++, libsodium

In my C++ project I'm using libsodium library to create and verify the signature of a message.

To verify the signature I'm using the libsodium `crypto_sign_open` function in this way

```
bool Signature::signatureVerification(const char* content, unsigned char* unsigned_message)
{
    bool verified;

    unsigned long long unsigned_message_len;

    if (crypto_sign_open(unsigned_message, &unsigned_message_len, (const unsigned char *)content, signed_message_len, pk) != 0)
    {
        verified = false;
        std::cout << "incorrect signature " << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        verified = true;
    }
    //print variable unsigned_message
    return verified;
}
```

If I "print" the variable `unsigned_message` I get the unsigned message followed by some characters coming from the signature. For example, if the message is 'hello', after the signature verification I get 'hello�*�'.

For now I "solved" the issue using the original length of the message (stored in the variable `unsigned_message_len`) to truncate the message returned by the function.

What could be the issue? Why in the `unsigned_message` variable there are some additional characters and not only the original message?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you don't have a null terminator, try adding + 1 after unsigned_message wherever that is being printed from. Your code obviously is going to print random characters out after the text because it is 'unisgned' meaning it does not have a signed data bit value. + 1 should terminate the random symbols.

Comment: The problem is not the printing of the variable, I use the value of the variable as an identifier but in this way I never get the correct id.

Comment: I realize that, and my response was that you are missing a null or zero-terminating character. If you use strlen it is not necessary but other wise were you either std::cout or print unsigned_message it must be unsigned_message + 1 in order to terminate the rest of the character symbols you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `unsigned_message` should have been preallocated in order to receive `unsigned_message_len` bytes.

Is it the case? Your code snippet doesn't show that part.

Did the length of the original message include the terminating `\0`?

If you used `strlen()`, it is not the case, so printing it will print your string, followed that anything until there's (by accident) a `\0` byte somewhere in memory. Or until it hits a guard page and crashes.

The issue is not really about signatures here. Strings must be zero-terminated if they don't have an explicit length.